# Python scraping webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping, html

I am trying to pull only the links and their text from a webpage line by line and insert text and link into a dictionary.  Without using beautiful soup or a regex.

i keep getting this error:

error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "F:/Homework7-2.py", line 13, in <module>
 link2 = link1.split("href=")[1]
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

code:

```
import urllib.request
url = "http://www.facebook.com" 
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
mylinks = {}
links = page.readline().decode('utf-8')


for items in links:
  links = page.readline().decode('utf-8')
  if "a href=" in links:
     links = page.readline().decode('utf-8')
     link1 = links.split(">")[0]
     link2 = link1.split("href=")[1]
     mylinks = link2
     print(mylinks)
```

Comment: it can anything......i was using facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336915/python-scraping-webpages")
#  find all a tags with href attributes
for a in BeautifulSoup(r.content).find_all("a",href=True):
    # print each href
    print(a["href"])
```

Obviously that is a very broad example but will get you started, if you want specific urls you can narrow your search to certain elements but it will be different for all webpages. You won't find much easier tools to use for parsing than [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: so how do i get the link text with the href?  ex: [<a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/" rel="license">attribution required</a>]  ........i need the attribution required part

Comment: You mean  `print(a.text)`?

Comment: can show how to do without using beautiful soup or regex?